# Automatic generating private key in EF4 without Identity column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-4

Is there any way to automatically generate primary key (int data type) **without using Identity properties**? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Express Edition and Entity Framework 4 (that integrated in Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: The **best, simplest and most reliable way** to do this ***IS*** using an `IDENTITY` column, since the database handles everything for you, and it's guaranteed to be concurrency-safe. Why are you excluding this perfect option from the get go?

Comment: Because I was doing experiment with IDENTITY column and I was not satisfied with results. I set tinyint IDENTITY column and added 255 rows, after that, overflow exception was continuously thrown even after I deleted all rows from table. That means database engine does not check which values are free to use, but only last used value. Imagine 1 000 000 rows added, deleted and added again - you have 2 000 000 unusable numbers now. Best solution I found is change int indexes to GUID indexes and generate unique indexes on client or on server using computed column (I do not know how yet).

Comment: Yes, that's the way the `IDENTITY` works - once a value has been given out, it's **never** recycled! Just use a more appropriate datatype - like `INT` which gives you potentially 4 **billion** possible values.....

Comment: I am not sure about 4 billions, int is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and I am sure that database engine does not assign negative numbers. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: You can **easily** have an `IDENTITY` column that starts at -2 billion and goes to +2 billion --> gives you 4 billion values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best, simplest and most reliable way to do this IS using an IDENTITY column, since the database handles everything for you, and it's guaranteed to be concurrency-safe.